# Powershell Word Document Formatting

Tags: powershell, cpu-word

I am using this Code to create a Word Doucment, Name it and Save it to a user area on a fileserver for a large cohort of people.

I have had a look online and found a few ways to incorporate formatting, does anyone have a simple method of trying to add;

1. Font Size
2. Font
3. Line Spacing

I believe the Font/Font Size is fairly straight forward, but the linespacing might be a bit more complex!

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know! Thank you in advance, have a good day

````
$Word.Visible = $false;
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Add();
$Section = $Doc.Sections.Item(1);
$Header = $Section.Headers.Item(1);
$Header.Range.Text = "$FirstName $SecondName $ID Activity 1";
$Doc.SaveAs("$fileserver\${date}${time}-${FourID}\Desktop\activity 1_${ID}_${FirstName}_${SecondName}.docx");
$Word.Quit()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```ps
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $false;
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Add();
$Section = $Doc.Sections.Item(1);
$Header = $Section.Headers.Item(1);
$Header.Range.Text = "$FirstName $SecondName $ID Activity 1";

$objRange = $Doc.Range()
$objRange.Font.Name = “Arial”
$objRange.Font.Size = 10
$objRange.Font.Spacing = 1.0
$objRange.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 1

$Doc.SaveAs("$fileserver\${date}${time}-${FourID}\Desktop\activity 1_${ID}_${FirstName}_${SecondName}.docx");
$Word.Quit()
```

This worked for me.

Comment: The Font and Font Size works perfect, whenever I set the line spacing it seems to overlap the text when I am typing on a new line! Font spacing also works fine, I just cant get the line spacing after words to work :(

Comment: @DanielDeLaWarr did you try different values and check if it works at all in your document? 
Read more about the object here: [MS-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraphformat.linespacing)

Comment: I've manage to get it working, noticed about the object using LinesToPoints! So double space required 24 :) Thank you so much!